# ADO not recognising old-style SQL joins. Don't know how to use new-style syntax in this particular query

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, left-join, ado

I'm coding in VBA, using ADO to query an Access-compatible (JET) database. I have the following query, which works just fine:

```
SELECT
   Answers.UserName AS UserName,
   COUNT(Answers.Correct) AS CorrectAnswers
FROM
   Answers
WHERE
   Answers.QuizID=17
   AND (SELECT COUNT(A.UserName) FROM Answers A WHERE A.QuizID=17 AND A.UserName=Answers.UserName)=30
GROUP BY Answers.UserName
```

This is basically a Q&A quiz whereby every answer is written into the Answers table. One column of the Answers table is "UserName", which contains the logon ID of the user who submitted the answer.

However instead of the logon ID, I want to display the user's full name. This is already stored in a separate table, "Users". In the "Users" table there are two columns: UserName and FullName.

Naturally, the correct way to display the full name would be with a join as follows:

```
SELECT
   Users.FullName AS FullName,
   COUNT(Answers.Correct) AS CorrectAnswers
FROM
   Answers,
   Users
WHERE
   Answers.QuizID=17
   AND (SELECT COUNT(A.UserName) FROM Answers A WHERE A.QuizID=17 AND A.UserName=Answers.UserName)=30
   AND Users.UserName=Answers.UserName
GROUP BY Users.UserName
```

This also works... just as long as the UserName exists in the Users table. However if for whatever reason the user is not registered in the Users table, instead of returning NULL, the record is not selected altogether.

In the "old-style" join syntax, I would solve this by adding a (+) symbol on the relevant line in the above code, so it reads:

```
AND Users.UserName=Answers.UserName(+)
```

This would ensure that all records are returned, even if the match does not exist in the Users table. However when I try this, ADO throws up an error: `Extra ( in query expression... etc`. I'm presuming that this is because ADO does not recognise the (+) syntax.

So the question is either, whether there is a way to get ADO to recognise (+) joins; or how should I write the query in the "new style" join syntax to get it to do what I want?

**What I've tried:**

```
SELECT
   Users.FullName AS UserName,
   COUNT(Answers.Correct) AS CorrectAnswers
FROM
   Answers,
   RIGHT JOIN Users U on Answers.Username = U.UserName
WHERE
   Answers.QuizID=17
   AND (SELECT COUNT(A.UserName) FROM Answers A WHERE A.QuizID=17 AND A.UserName=Answers.UserName)=30
GROUP BY Users.FullName
```

But this doesn't work. It just throws `Syntax Error`. I have also tried it without the comma following `Answers`, to no avail.

There are plenty of online resources telling people how to use the new-style joins. However I haven't seen anything showing me how to do this properly, where the query includes other clauses in `WHERE`. Indeed, I find that all new-style join examples are relatively simplistic where it's demonstrated how to perform a single join on two tables - where there are no other elements to the query. However when the query is even a touch more complicated, it's unclear how the syntax should be used.

Comment: Remove the comma before RIGHT. Except that, the syntax is fine.

Comment: @jarlh I already tried that, as stated in the question. The error becomes: `No value given for one or more of the required parameters`.

Comment: That's another problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a `LEFT` join of `Answers` to `Users` based `ON` the columns `UserName` in both tables.
This means that all rows of `Answers` will be returned even if there are no matches in `Users`.
But there is also another problem: in the `SELECT` list you have the column `FullName` although you don't include it in the `GROUP BY` clause and this is not allowed.
So I included it also in `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
   a.UserName, u.FullName,
   COUNT(a.Correct) AS CorrectAnswers
FROM Answers a LEFT JOIN Users u
ON u.UserName = a.UserName
WHERE a.QuizID=17
  AND 
 (SELECT COUNT(aa.UserName) FROM Answers aa WHERE aa.QuizID = a.QuizID AND aa.UserName = a.UserName) = 30
GROUP BY a.UserName, u.FullName
```

Although I don't know the reason for the subquery in the `WHERE` clause, I believe it can be moved in a `HAVING` clause like this:

```
SELECT
   a.UserName, u.FullName,
   COUNT(a.Correct) AS CorrectAnswers
FROM Answers a LEFT JOIN Users u
ON u.UserName = a.UserName
WHERE a.QuizID=17
GROUP BY a.UserName, u.FullName
HAVING COUNT(*) = 30
```

Comment: Thanks - this seems to work! The next step, of course, is to substitute UserName for FullName in the SELECT clause, in case FullName is null. NVL doesn't seem to work (I'm used to working in oracle). IsNull isn't recognised either. I know this is a different question, but could you advise? ;)

Comment: If you want only 1 column, change `a.UserName, u.FullName`  to `COALESCE(u.FullName, a.UserName)`

Comment: using COALESCE results in an error: `Method 'Open' of object '_Recordset' failed`. Are you sure COALESCE is recognised by ADO?

Comment: Update: COALESCE doesn't work, but IIF(Condition, ValueIfTrue, ValueIfFalse) does work! Thanks.

Comment: If it is MS Access that you are using, then no coalesce() does not work.

Comment: But you can use: `Nz(u.FullName, a.UserName)`. About Nz(): https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c

Comment: I also tried Nz - but it was not a recognised function. I'm coding in Excel VBA, with the ADO extension. It interacts with an Access-compatible .mdb file.

Comment: If Nz() isn't recognized then IIF() is the only option.